# How to set different home app in android when in CAR_MODE/CAR_DOCK

Tags: android, android-studio, dashboard, homescreen

I was building Car Dashboard app and can't find any usefull way to change home app when phone is docked in car
I have dock station, and phone is going to car mode, but when I click on home button it go to home screen. I want to change this to go to my app when car mode is active. There are simmilar app like "HTC Car" or "Automate" working this way.

I have set `CAR_DOCK` category and App was started when I connect phone to docking station

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_DOCK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_MODE" />

    </intent-filter>
```

but when i disconnect phone from cardock app was still run.

**How to set home app when docked (car_mode/car_dock) and change it back when undocked (car_mode exit)?**

Answer (score 0):

I have simple solution, but it works fine for me on android 7.0
I need to add line

```
<meta-data android:name="android.dock_home" android:value="true" />
```

in section `<activity>` in AndroidManifest.xml

Aplication when in dock station is autorun and home button was changed to home screen. I need to monitor undocking and then close app. 
If someone have better solution please share it :)